# Zero inflated distribution in R

Tags: r

What are some different packages in R that contain in built function to simulate the Zero inflated distributions, related to the popular discrete models like the Poisson, Negative Binomial, COM-Poisson, Poisson Inverse Gaussian, Poisson-Lindley except the 'iZid' package.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have an existing function that generates random deviates from a non-zero-inflated distribution, you can write a wrapper (or *decorator*) that creates a zero-inflated-deviate simulator. The only assumption I've made here is that the first argument of the original function is called `n` and specifies the number of random deviates to pick.

For example, if we want to extend `rbinom` to return zero-inflated binomial deviates ...

```r
ziversion <- function(rfun) {
   f <- function(n, ..., zi) {
      x <- rfun(n, ...)
      x <- ifelse(runif(n) < zi, 0, x)
      return(x)
   }
   return(f)
}
rzibinom <- ziversion(rbinom)
set.seed(101)
rzibinom(10, size = 10, prob = 0.2, zi = 0.5)
##  [1] 1 0 3 2 0 1 2 0 0 0
```

`zi` is the zero-inflation probability.  With a little bit of effort the code could be made more efficient ...

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at the [CRAN Task View on Distributions](https://cran.r-project.org/web/views/Distributions.html). This is a curated look at R packages that help you work with distributions. You can search the page for "inflated" to quickly find the relevant parts.